# When to use equal sign after declare a variable with closure in Swift

Tags: swift

I just saw the sample code from Apple:

```
let timeRemainingFormatter: NSDateComponentsFormatter = {
    let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .Pad
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.Minute, .Second]

    return formatter
}()

var timeRemainingString: String {
    let components = NSDateComponents()
    components.second = Int(max(0.0, timeRemaining))

    return timeRemainingFormatter.stringFromDateComponents(components)!
}
```

The question is: The constant and the variable are both declared with a closure, but one with an equal sign, the other is not. Why?

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for reply. So the first one is declaring a constant as a closure, the second is using a closure for its property?

Comment: The first you have a closure method that initializes a constant. The second it is a read only computed property where you are omiting the get and its braces

Comment: A computed property with a getter but no setter is known as a read-only computed property. A read-only computed property always returns a value, and can be accessed through dot syntax, but cannot be set to a different value.
You must declare computed properties—including read-only computed properties—as variable properties with the var keyword, because their value is not fixed. The let keyword is only used for constant properties, to indicate that their values cannot be changed once they are set as part of instance initialization.

Comment: You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by removing the get keyword and its braces:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`()` says "execute now and return the results." Now for a long-winded answer:

```
let timeRemainingFormatter: NSDateComponentsFormatter = {
    // ...
}() // <- The '()' means "execute now and give me the formatter"
```

`timeRemainingFormatter` will be calculated **once**, at init time, and the value will be stored. The parenthesis indicates that the closure should be executed immediately and the results returned, in this case to be stored as a property.

```
var timeRemainingString: String {
    // ...
}
```

`timeRemainingString` will be calculated each time it is called.

---

## Functions vs. Closures

More generally, in Swift, functions are just named closures. Defining a function like:

```
func myFunc() -> Void {
    print("Function")
}
```

is pretty much the same as defining a closure like:

```
let myClosure: () -> Void = {
    print("Closure")
}
```

In both cases, you have a name (`myFunc`/`myClosure`), a call signature(`() -> Void`), and a block of code (`{ print(...) }`).

Just as you would call your function:

```
myFunc()
```

you could call your stored closure like:

```
myClosure()
```

and both would print.

Functions are pretty much just a convenience for defining named closures.

---

## Using Functions and Closures in Context

Let's say you had a global function and a global stored closure, defined respectively as:

```
func myIntFunc() -> Int { return 1 }
let myIntClosure: () -> Int = { return 2 }
```

The similarities should be pretty obvious.

Now you want to use them in a class as properties. You'd do

```
class MyClass {
    let funcInt:    Int = myIntFunc()    // would resolve to 1
    let closureInt: Int = myIntClosure() // would resolve to 2
}
```

Notice how you have `()` at the end of both of those. That says "execute my function/closure to get the `Int` now."

Now imagine you don't want to define a global closure; you'd rather put that code in your class, to keep things organized. So you do:

```
class MyClass {
    let funcInt:    Int = myIntFunc()    // would resolve to 1
    let closureInt: Int = { return 2 }() // would resolve to 2
}
```

You still need to execute your closure to get the `Int` out of it, just like the function. So you place `()` after it, just like the function.

---

## Calculated Properties

Lastly, we will touch on the "calculated property".

```
var timeRemainingString: String {
    // ...
}
```

You can think of this as a way of writing a function that takes no arguments, and thus you get a short-cut call signature (you can treat it like a property). It's really like the closure is being stored by the property, but because it is a special notation, Swift knows to execute the closure and returns its result every time you call for the property. Thus this is a "calculated property".

When you call:

```
let timeRemaining = instance.timeRemainingString
```

Swift is really translating that to:

```
let timeRemaining = instance.timeRemainingString()
```

It's just adding the `()` for you to make the stored closure execute.

Things are actually a little more complicated than that, because you can define setter closures along with the getters we've just discussed, and even observer closures as well. Swift will just dispatch to the correct closure depending on what kind of operation you're trying to perform.